Removing Independent Variable Uncorrelated with All Other Variables in Linear Regression
I've been looking at Wooldrige's Introductory Econometrics and came across the following section related to omitted variables in multiple regression here
The section essentially says that if an independent variable is uncorrelated with all others in the linear regression model, then we can essentially treat it as a part of the error $u$. I was wondering why this is true?
I know that we can write the model as $y = \beta_0 + \beta_2x_2 + \cdots + \beta_kx_k + (u + \beta_1x_1)$ and try to prove that $E[u + \beta_1x_1 \mid x_2, \cdots x_k] = E[u + \beta_1x_1]$, which comes down to proving $E[x_1 \mid x_2, \cdots, x_k] = E[x_1]$. But I just don't see how $x_1$ being uncorrelated with $x_2, \cdots, x_k$ imply that $x_1$ is mean-independent of $x_2, \cdots, x_k$

Hi: independence from $x_2, \ldots, x_{k}$ means that knowing those respective values gives you no new information about $x_1$. Therefore, the expected value of $x_1$ given those values is just the expected value of $x_1$.
